# How to set the Google Cloud Platform Project of a container-bound script using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

So my app creates spreadsheets programmatically as our projects expand (a new spreadsheet for each project).  Each spreadsheet has a container-bound script that has some javascript in it to give the spreadsheet some extra functionality.  Now I need all the scripts attached to these spreadsheets to use the same GCP project.  I know how to set the GCP project manually ([from this article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)), but I need to be able to set the GCP project programmatically when the spreadsheets are created.

I figure this can be done using UrlFetchApp, but I can't figure out the url that the "Set Project" button uses to make this happen.  I tried inspecting the html on that settings page, but it's like 16000 lines of code, and while I found the button, I can't figure out the url it posts to.

Can someone help me out here?  I need either the formatting of the url post, or another method to set the GCP project of a script with Apps Script.

Here's my code that I'm planning to use:

```
function changeGCPproject() {
  const scriptId = '1Q8Frqjb6vh5....';
  const gcpProjectNumber = '596....';

  const url = `https://script.google.com/home/projects/${scriptId}/whateverformat?projectNumber=${gcpProjectNumber}`; //this is the url formatting that I need
  
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const params = {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to deploy an add-on

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this programmatically. Can you provide more details on why you `need all the scripts attached to these spreadsheets to use the same GCP project`?

Comment: @lamlichus, for logging and error reporting.  I use logging in particular to track activity and processing time in the case that we reach our server time quota.

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest [deploying your script as an add-on](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons) so that it can be used in all your spreadsheets. Do you think that would be an appropriate solution for you?